# Eclipse cannot find sources for a gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have created a Gradle project on Eclipse with this dependency:

`// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.onyxdevtools/onyx-database
    compile group: 'com.onyxdevtools', name: 'onyx-database', version: '2.1.3'`

After a successful *Refresh Gradle Project*, I can see in *Project and External Dependencies* the [Onyx](https://www.onyxdevtools.com) Database jar and I can import all the annotations and classes that I would like to use.

My problem is that I cannot see the sources for all the Onyx classes, as Eclipse shows always this message:

`Source not found
The Jar of this class file belongs to container 'Project and External Dependencies' which does not allow modifications to source attachments on its entries.`

Since I am learning how to use Onyx for a project it would really helps me to actually see the code that I am using. How can I tell Eclipse where to look for the sources?

Comment: https://steffenschaefer.github.io/gwt-gradle-plugin/doc/latest/eclipse

Comment: check this above link